# Detect Application Launch Event

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to somehow hook into the system event of an Application Launch in Mac OS X? For example, let's say that I want a simple script or program to run each time a specific application is opened. I'm hoping that there is some sort of Cocoa API to do this, but I have not found one yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out on my own. There's a class called NSWorkspace that contains a NSNotificationCenter that you can add observers too. I added an observer for name "NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification" and this seems to do the trick.